# Processing sketch works in Java but not in JavaScript mode

Tags: javascript, processing, processing-ide

I wrote a processing sketch for depicting the parallel coordinates visualization. The problem is that though it works fine in `Java` mode but shows a blank screen in `JavaScript` Mode. Can someone tell me what the problem is? I am using Processing 2.0. The error I receive in Firefox is as follows:

```
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead. @ chrome://smarterwiki/content/jquery.js:3527
Error in parsing value for 'image-rendering'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://127.0.0.1:56763/
ReferenceError: Float is not defined @ http://127.0.0.1:56763/processing.js:10175
```

I cannot provide the code because it's part of a homework I still need to submit. Also, seeing the last line, I tried to replace all the instances of the `float` type with `var` type in the `JavaScript` mode but it didn't help.

Comment: Well `Processing` has multiple modes. `Java` is the default and you need to run the sketch in `JavaScript` mode to run it in a browser.

Comment: How are you calling size()? You may be using a rendering mode not available in javascript mode.

Comment: I am using `Float` which can't be understood by `JavaScript`. That much I know by now.

Comment: The way I use to debug processingjs apps is to move a background method call until the background no longer changes. For example right after you set size add a `background(255,0,0);` line. If you see the background turning red, then your program starts properly. Move that background line lower after each line to find where exactly this happens, and tell us here! Do you really need `Float` btw? Can't you just use `float`? (They are different)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that I was using `Float.isNaN()` and `Float.MAX_VALUE` in parts of my code where I couldn't do without them.

I got this answer in the Processing [forum](http://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/370/processing-sketch-works-in-java-but-not-in-javascript-mode#Item_7) which worked like a charm.

> For MAX_VALUE:
>   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.lang.Float.MAX_VALUE
>   And see also
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Infinity
>
> For NaN:
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN